# Get number of conditional occurances using multidimensional arrays

Tags: php

I want to count the number of times the `$items_array` goes in to the `$condition_array` based on the `item_id` and `quantity`.

```
<?php
    $items_array = [
        ['item_id'=>1, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>3],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>6]
    ];

    $condition_array = [
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>2]
    ];

    $count = ?; // Should equal 3
?>
```

In this example the `$count` should be 3 because both `$condition_array` `item_id`'s exist in `$item_array` and the respective quantities go in to each other 3 times (6/2 and 3/1).

Further examples showing desired `$count` value based off this logic:

```
<?php
    $items_array = [
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>2]
    ];

    $condition_array = [
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>2]
    ];

    $count = ?; // Should equal 0 (because item_id 11 missing from $items_array)
?>


<?php
    $items_array = [
        ['item_id'=>1, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>2],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>1]
    ];

    $condition_array = [
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>2]
    ];

    $count = ?; // Should equal 0 (because all the quantities don't go in to each other (item_id 12 1/2))
?>


<?php
    $items_array = [
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>2],
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>1]
    ];

    $condition_array = [
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>2]
    ];

    $count = ?; // Should equal 1 (exact match)
?>

<?php
    $items_array = [
        ['item_id'=>1, 'quantity'=>4],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>1],
        ['item_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>1]
    ];

    $condition_array = [
        ['item_id'=>1, 'quantity'=>2],
        ['item_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>1]
    ];

    $count = ?; // Should equal 1 (because despite item_id 1 going in to $condition_array twice (4/2), item_id 12 only has 1 quantity in $items_array, if item_id 12  had a quantity of 2 in $item_array then $count would equal 2)
?>
```

I've been looking through https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php but can't seem to find the right function to use for this.

Comment: I'd recommend you to reorganize your arrays first and make both of them this way ```$array [$item_id => $quantity]``` and then use ```foreach``` loop through ```$condition_array``` with checking existence of every condition item in ```$items_array``` by ```array_key_exists``` and getting the lowest ```$count```

Comment: @Lothric I understand your recommendation up until "and getting the lowest $count". Once I've done `if(array_key_exists($item_id, $items_array))` inside the `foreach($condition_array as $item_id => $quantity)` loop, I'm not sure what you're suggesting I do next? See image: https://i.imgur.com/gHfB0fP.png

Comment: if I got it right, your ```$count``` is a minimum result of every dividing ```$items_array``` quantity by ```$condition_array``` quantity, isn't it? So find it in the loop, and if some key doesn't exist in ```$items_array``` just return zero.